# creat new managed object using coredata

Tags: ios, xcode, nsentitydescription

i'm trying to create a new object and save it to core data. even my code is correct as syntax and logic -as i've learned- ,but I can't understand why these errors occur.

[image: Errors]

Comment: importing "Appdelegate.h" had fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

at the top of the file.